# How to not count cells across sheets which do not contain text?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Currently I have a formula which calculates the text contained within a given cell across multiple sheets i.e.:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!G3:G1151, "COMPLETE") + COUNTIF(Sheet2!G3:G1151, "COMPLETE")
```

I need to **not calculate (Count)** a cell if it **does not contain text**, i.e.:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!G3:G1151, "COMPLETE") + COUNTIF(Sheet2!G3:G1151, "COMPLETE") + !COUNTIF(Sheet2!G3:G1151, "COMPLETE")
```

Any ideas? thanks

Comment: Could you please provide a sample sheet ? Could you maybe illustrate with an example what is exactly the thing you want to count? 
As your question right know it seems like your are counting all the `COMPLETE` cells and it is already excluding the cells that doesn't contain text.

Comment: If this is Google-Sheets, please, remove excel tag, and add google-sheets tag

Comment: *I need to not calculate (Count) a cell if it does not contain text* Can you please clarify this? It sounds really confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Not is `<>`:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!G3:G1151, "<>COMPLETE") + COUNTIF(Sheet2!G3:G1151, "<>COMPLETE") + COUNTIF(Sheet2!G3:G1151, "<>COMPLETE")
```